# Tag <img> in HTML (Web) and Cookies in Server (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

I'm sorry first if this question is not appropriate to be asked here.

Here is my problem :

> my page will contains 10 - 500 images (at most) with 1 button below each image
>
> while at first, all of the images wont be shown,
>
> and the user can click the button to show that images.

I am using `ajax` to retrieve `image_file_path` from Database to get the right image for the right button.

but sometimes , they just don't have any image related to that button, so I will display `Default Images`.

My question is should I use `cookies` for this `default images` or is it handled already by user's browser or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically Images are stored on server and once they are loaded into browser, they will cache into browser with that name and page. SO once you have downloaded that image, then it will 50% case shown from local cache.

Lets take example for more understanding
You page as 10-500 Images and when you click on any show image button it only fetch the name and that time you update the src tag in image, now browser will check that image is available in the local cache, if yes then it will display from it. Otherwise fetch from server.

Currently browser are became more smart then previously.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use cookies just use `default_image` url in `ajax` responce if there is no image associated with particular button.

In such case default image will be shown.

you have to pass a url in `<img>` tag.
If that image is stored in cookies then it will be riveted form cookies otherwise from the URL